# Package flutter_launcher_icon don't remove adaptive icons

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to setup my Flutter project and I have a problem with the flutter_launcher_icon package.
When I set the background and foreground of the adaptive icon, the app icon works fine and everything is ok. However, once I delete them to go back to a classic icon, as the adaptive icon files have already been created, the package does not delete them, and I end up with the same icon...
I wanted to know if there was a way to force the package to delete the files it had created, or with a command, delete all the icon-related files in the res folder.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to android > app > src > main > res and delete all the drawable-dpi folders (except for the plain drawable folder), and the mipmap-any folder. Those folders contain the files for the adaptive icon, and without them Android just uses the regular icon.

Comment: For me, the `mipmap-anydpi-vXX`-Folder contained an XML that enabled adaptive icons. Removing that, fixed it.